# OpenLiberty mpRestClient tutorial feature definition could not be found

Tags: java, open-liberty

I was excited to read about OpenLiberty's [template interface feature](https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-rest-client.html#getting-started) to consume Rest endpoints. However, when I clone and run (liberty:run/liberty:debug) the sample project I see the following output in the console:

```
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for mpconfig-2.0
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for cdi-2.0
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for mprestclient-2.0
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for jsonp-1.1
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for jaxrs-2.1
[INFO] [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 2.673 seconds.
```

I can't see what step I missed in the tutorial thus I am glad for any hints.

EDIT: More log from the console

```
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using serverDirectory : C:\Users\niod\sandbox\guide-microprofile-rest-client\finish\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer.
[INFO] Installing assembly...
[INFO] Expanding: C:\Users\niod\.m2\repository\io\openliberty\openliberty-kernel\21.0.0.9\openliberty-kernel-21.0.0.9.zip into C:\Users\niod\sandbox\guide-microprofile-rest-client\finish\target\liberty
[INFO] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\niod\sandbox\guide-microprofile-rest-client\finish\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer
[INFO] CWWKM2144I: Update server configuration file server.xml from C:\Users\niod\sandbox\guide-microprofile-rest-client\finish\src\main\liberty\config\server.xml.
[INFO] CWWKM2001I: Invoke command is ["C:\Users\niod\sandbox\guide-microprofile-rest-client\finish\target\liberty\wlp\bin\server.bat", debug, defaultServer].
[INFO] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 7777
[INFO] Launching defaultServer (Open Liberty 21.0.0.9/wlp-1.0.56.cl210920210824-2341) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 13.0.2+8 (en_US)
[INFO] [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[INFO] [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\Users\niod\sandbox\guide-microprofile-rest-client\finish\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\configDropins\overrides\liberty-plugin-variable-config.xml
```

Comment: Which directory (start/finish) did you use? I just did clone, `cd finish` and `mvn liberty:run` and it started successfully: `[INFO] [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [cdi-2.0, jaxrs-2.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jndi-1.0, jsonp-1.1, mpConfig-2.0, mpRestClient-2.0, servlet-4.0].`

Comment: I tried both start and finish folders, they both run fine. So I'd suggest to do `mvn clean` and `mvn liberty:run` again. Maybe some of the dependencies didnt download correctly for you.

Comment: What version of liberty-maven-plugin are you using?

Comment: `mvn liberty:debug` will not install the required features. `mvn liberty:run` should. You should see `[INFO] Installing features: [mpconfig-2.0, cdi-2.0, mprestclient-2.0, jsonp-1.1, jaxrs-2.1]` quite early in the build log.